# Visual studio 2019 not showing report tab

Tags: c#

I am using visual studio 2019 for a c# project but couldn't create a report and the reporting tab is not available under add new item option.

Thanks in advance!!

I have installed Microsoft RDLC designer and Microsoft reporting service projects as well.

Comment: Did you check the "Extensions -> manage extensions" and install the Microsoft Reporting Projects one? Most recent VS versions have that as a free extension in their marketplace

Comment: Yes I have installed but It don't seems to work.